# How to switch database without closing groovy Sql connection

Tags: mysql, database, groovy

I created a connection with MySQL DB with 'test' database. I want to switch to another database say 'test2'. How can we do that using groovy.

Comment: Connect to both databases and use the connections alternatively (?).

Comment: Sure. But that means we are creating that many of connections, which is not right.

Comment: Drop the first connection, and create another one

Comment: I think those are the only 2 options

Answer (score 3):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html

In MySQL the command:

```
use db1;
```

From groovy it'll be something like

```
def dnName = 'db1'
sql.execute( "use $dbName" as String )
```

But beware, if you don't have dedicated connection (connection pool for example) this is a bad idea to switch database.

Comment: nice idea!  A connection with a mutable database makes me scared though  

Comment: Great. Works. Thanks.

Comment: @PankajShinde Please remember to accept and upvote the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Yes. Done that.